# Is it possible to load a Google Ads custom report via API into production DB

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Looking through the API documentation it seems that there's currently no way to access a custom report via the API. If this is, in fact, the case, is there a workaround to make this possible?

The goal is to get a modified version of this report shown on the web interface:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to build the report yourself and call it with the API unfortunately.

Depending on how complex the report is, it can be done pretty quickly. You can quickly generate the GAQL needed for your APU query using this tool: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v7/overview_query_builder

This will save you typing out all the resources manually, and will even validate it for you.

If you're stuck, let us know what report you're trying to generate and we can help with the GAQL.

Comment: So I've looked into the GAQL Query Builder but I can't seem to get a similar table to  what I want. Do you by any chance know how to replicate the location view from the web ui as shown in my post? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you query the location view? Can you post your query?

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v8/location_view_query_builder

Comment: So I queried like this: `SELECT location_view.resource_name, metrics.average_cost, metrics.average_cpc, metrics.clicks, metrics.conversions, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.cost_per_conversion, metrics.impressions, metrics.interactions, metrics.interaction_rate, campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.end_date, campaign.start_date, segments.date FROM location_view WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS`
Edit: As you can see, I tried to get a few more features into the report than just what is present in the actual location view. But how do I get the 'Targeted Location' Field from the UI view